# What's the best way to set up redirection on domain to an specific page

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, server, dns, hosting

I have example-bulkorder.com domain which is connected to ecommerce hosting (Business Catalyst).

This site doesn't need ecommerce anymore so I create a simple page on example.com/bulkorder which has a form that send email to me so that I can handle bulk orders manually via email.

At the moment I just set up redirection with javascript but when I unsubscribe Business Catalyst hosting, I will need to find a way to set up this redirection from example-bulkorder.com domain to example.com/bulkorder

Is there a way to do this with AWS or should I just kill the old domain?
I am not worried about all pages under the domain but at least the main url to be redirected.

Or should I just let the old domain goes to broken link and let people to find out that the url is not available? What's the best solution? I want to keep the old domain in case I need it with separate ecommerce system in the future.

Comment: I found this... haven't tried yet, https://www.vivekmchawla.com/how-to-set-up-url-forwarding-in-aws-using-only-route-53-and-s3/ maybe it's a solution to my case??

Comment: Yes, that looks ok. Maybe just use 302 instead of 301.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following procedure to redirect your domain

**Requirements**

- A hosted zone for the domain example-bulkorder.com is hosted in Amazon Route 53.
- You have permissions to add resource records to the hosted zone of example.com.
- You have permissions to create an Amazon S3 bucket.
- You are able to create an S3 bucket with the exact name for example.com.
  Note: The sites must be HTTP because the redirect cannot connect to S3 over HTTPS.

  1. In the Amazon S3 console, create an S3 bucket with the exact name as example-bulkorder.com.

     **Note**: S3 bucket names must be globally unique. If the bucket name you need is already in use, this solution cannot be used.
  2. Select the bucket you just created, and then choose Properties. Expand the Static Website Hosting drop-down menu, and then choose Redirect all requests to another hostname.
  3. In the Redirect, all requests to another hostname field, enter example.com/bulkorder and then choose Save.
  4. In the Route 53 console, select the hosted zone named example-bulkorder.com.
- Create a resource record for example.com with the following values:
- Record Type: Choose A IPv4 address.
- Alias: Choose Yes.
- Alias Target: Select the blank value field, expand the drop-down menu, and then choose your S3 bucket under the heading S3 Website Endpoints.
- Routing Policy: Choose Simple.
- Evaluate Health Target: Choose No and then choose to Create.

  **Note**: The drop-down menu might take a few moments to populate your bucket name.
  You should now be able to redirect example-bulkorder.com to example.com/bulkorder.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this serverless by using [Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-) (probably the easiest way), just need to create a **page rule** to redirect your domain to your desired endpoint.

Check this post: [How do I perform URL forwarding or redirects with Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-)?

Within AWS is also possible you have more options, one of this is using an S3 bucket, check this article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/